# Xamarin Android Rest API to PassSlot - nameResolutionFailure

Tags: android, json, rest, xamarin, httprequest

I'm using a REST API to access PassSlot in an attempt to generate a pass / coupon. It seems that when i run the program i get the error: "Error: NameResolutionFailure".

I have:

```
public static async Task<string> SendAndReceiveJsonRequest()
        {
            string responseStr = null;
            string uri = "https://api.passslot.com/v1/templates/my-template-ID/pass";

            // Create a json string with a single key/value pair.

            var json = new JObject (new JProperty ("lastName", lastName),
                                    new JProperty ("firstName", firstName),
                                    new JProperty ("percentOff", percentOff),
                                    new JProperty ("offerDescription", offerDescription),
                                    new JProperty ("entityName", entityName),
                                    new JProperty ("expiry", expiry));

            //Console.WriteLine ("Jake's JSON " + json.ToString ());

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient ())

            {    

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("My-Key-Here-xxx-xxx-xxx");
                //create the http request content

                HttpContent content = new StringContent(json.ToString());


                try
                {
                    // Send the json to the server using POST

                    Task<HttpResponseMessage> getResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
                    // Wait for the response and read it to a string var

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await getResponse;
                    responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error communicating with the server: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            return responseStr;
        }
```

I'm running this on Android 4.4 via a Nexus 4. I'm on 3G (not wifi).

Any hints as to what might be happening here and why i'm getting the error.

Comment: The problem seems to be when running in debug mode. It's fine when in release mode.

Comment: Maybe try posting some of the Application output

Answer (score 0):

In case the url request is in local network, Check if you url ip is set in the hosts device (the **hosts** setting of the smartphone, tablet, whatever you are using to test)

PD. 
To edit the hosts setting device in android you may use this app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nilhcem.hostseditor